# What tools can be used to check the dependency dll used by a VB program?

Tags: c#, vb.net

We have a program written in VB, when it runs in Windows XP, it works  well, but when run in Windows server  2003, it failed. I am sure this caused by  the wrong dll referenced by the VB program, so I would like to know if someone could suggest me a tool to find out what dependency dll used by the VB program in different environments, so that I investigate on that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The crash should indicate which file its unable to use.  I would locate that file on the Windows XP installation and place it in the installation directory of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).